# Java inheritance: Why this program gives 0.0 in output

Tags: java, initialization, default-value

I have written this code. The output should calculate the interest of the Bank but it gives 0.0 as output. I have created a class named as Bank and extended it in ICICI class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bank
{
    static double rate;
    // n = number of years
    public  double calculateInterest( double PrincipalAmount, double n)
    {
        double interest;
        interest = (PrincipalAmount * n*rate) /100; // interest formula
        return  interest;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter PrincipalAmount :" );
        double PrincipalAmount = s1.nextDouble();

        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Number of Years :" );
        double n = s2.nextDouble();

        ICICI ic;
        ic = new ICICI();// new object created of ICICI Class
        ic.rate = rate; // object call by reference
       System.out.print("Interest of ICICI is " +  ic.calculateInterest( PrincipalAmount,n));
    }
}

public class ICICI extends Bank
{
    double rate = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing following:

```
ic.rate = rate;
```

and rate is not initialized....

so `ic.rate = 0.0;`

you should by the way take a look at this:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html
- [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)
  and this
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 0):

calculateInterest method is using static rate variable not instance rate , inheritance does not apply on variable , it does not override variable. so default value of static rate will be 0.0 and hence calculateInterest will give 0.0 (because it is double)answer.

Comment: Even if we remove static, it will still refer to rate variable in the Bank class. So your logic does not hold.

Comment: @user3689942 even if it is non static variable you can not override it.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistakenly altered the assignment statement:

ic.rate = rate;

Instead, it should be :
rate= ic.rate;

Thanks!